# Accessing nodes by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

this might be a daft question but...

I'm just jquery to access an object using:

```
obj["surveySpec"]["3"]["Survey"]["5"]["description"];
```

the problem is that depending on the results it can be a different length, what does stay the same is the id of 42333

Is there a way to search for that ID and bring back the values?

I tried

```
var result2 = $.grep(obj2, function(e){ return e.id === 42333; });
```

but that didn't work

The object is:

```
Object
    Object
    id:1
    registration:"NA123"
    serviceVersion:"V2"
surveySpec:Array[7]
0:Object
1:Object
2:Object
3:Object
    Survey:Array[15]
    0:Object
    1:Object
    2:Object
    3:Object
    4:Object
    5:Object
    description:"survey results, 5, 2 and 3"
    id:42333
    items:Array[3]
    name:"survey results"
    value:"standard"
```

Comment: please serialize the sample object and post as string, it'll be helpful

Comment: If i serialize the entire thing it's huge. ill try and cut it down a bit.

Comment: :P create a sample and give as string?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var test = {
  id: 1,
  items: [
    {
      id: 11,
      description: "three",
      surveys: [
        {
          id: 121,
          description: "one"
        },
        {
          id: 122,
          description: "two"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 12,
      description: "seven"
    },
    {
      id: 13,
      description: "four",
      surveys: [
        {
          id: 131,
          description: "five"
        },
        {
          id: 132,
          description: "six"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

function findById(obj, id) {
  if (obj) {
    if (obj.id == id)
      return obj;
    for(var key in obj) {
      if ((typeof obj[key]).toLowerCase() != "string" && 
          (typeof obj[key]).toLowerCase() != "number") {
        var result = findById(obj[key], id);
        if (result)
          return result;
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
var result = findById(test, 131);
console.log("result:");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var myVar = '';
$.each(obj["surveySpec"],function(index,object){
      $.each(obj["survey"],function(ind,innerObject){
         if(innerOject.id === 42333){
            myVar = innerObject.description;
             return false;}
      });
    });
```

looks like this might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, i've tried that but it says mrVar is not defined when i try and output it to the console.

Comment: Define myVar outside the loops, try the code now, i edited it

Comment: Thanks i'll try that (and also I changed innerOject to innerObject